# How to convert nested JSON like this to a Data-frame? I tried using pandas json_normalize but still doesn't get a proper Data-frame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I am trying to make a DataFrame out of this JSON, It contains three keys which are Header, Column and Rows.
The problem is that the Rows contains a lot of Nesting and even the panda's json_normalize is unable to create a meaningful DataFrame out of this.

Here is the Json:

```
{'Header': {'Time': '2021-10-08T05:08:48-07:00',
      'ReportName': 'ProfitAndLoss',
      'DateMacro': 'this calendar year-to-date',
      'ReportBasis': 'Accrual',
      'StartPeriod': '2021-01-01',
      'EndPeriod': '2021-10-08',
      'SummarizeColumnsBy': 'Total',
      'Currency': 'USD',
      'Option': [{'Name': 'AccountingStandard', 'Value': 'GAAP'},
       {'Name': 'NoReportData', 'Value': 'false'}]},
     'Columns': {'Column': [{'ColTitle': '',
        'ColType': 'Account',
        'MetaData': [{'Name': 'ColKey', 'Value': 'account'}]},
       {'ColTitle': 'Total',
        'ColType': 'Money',
        'MetaData': [{'Name': 'ColKey', 'Value': 'total'}]}]},
     'Rows': {'Row': [{'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Income'}, {'value': ''}]},
        'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Design income', 'id': '82'},
            {'value': '2250.00'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Discounts given', 'id': '86'},
            {'value': '-89.50'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Landscaping Services', 'id': '45'},
             {'value': '1477.50'}]},
           'Rows': {'Row': [{'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Job Materials',
                 'id': '46'},
                {'value': ''}]},
              'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Fountains and Garden Lighting',
                   'id': '48'},
                  {'value': '2246.50'}],
                 'type': 'Data'},
                {'ColData': [{'value': 'Plants and Soil', 'id': '49'},
                  {'value': '2351.97'}],
                 'type': 'Data'},
                {'ColData': [{'value': 'Sprinklers and Drip Systems', 'id': '50'},
                  {'value': '138.00'}],
                 'type': 'Data'}]},
              'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Job Materials'},
                {'value': '4736.47'}]},
              'type': 'Section'},
             {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Labor', 'id': '51'},
                {'value': ''}]},
              'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Installation', 'id': '52'},
                  {'value': '250.00'}],
                 'type': 'Data'},
                {'ColData': [{'value': 'Maintenance and Repair', 'id': '53'},
                  {'value': '50.00'}],
                 'type': 'Data'}]},
              'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Labor'},
                {'value': '300.00'}]},
              'type': 'Section'}]},
           'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Landscaping Services'},
             {'value': '6513.97'}]},
           'type': 'Section'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Pest Control Services', 'id': '54'},
            {'value': '110.00'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Sales of Product Income', 'id': '79'},
            {'value': '912.75'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Services', 'id': '1'}, {'value': '503.55'}],
           'type': 'Data'}]},
        'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Income'}, {'value': '10200.77'}]},
        'type': 'Section',
        'group': 'Income'},
       {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Cost of Goods Sold'}, {'value': ''}]},
        'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Cost of Goods Sold', 'id': '80'},
            {'value': '405.00'}],
           'type': 'Data'}]},
        'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Cost of Goods Sold'},
          {'value': '405.00'}]},
        'type': 'Section',
        'group': 'COGS'},
       {'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Gross Profit'}, {'value': '9795.77'}]},
        'type': 'Section',
        'group': 'GrossProfit'},
       {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Expenses'}, {'value': ''}]},
        'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Advertising', 'id': '7'},
            {'value': '74.86'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Automobile', 'id': '55'},
             {'value': '113.96'}]},
           'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Fuel', 'id': '56'},
               {'value': '349.41'}],
              'type': 'Data'}]},
           'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Automobile'},
             {'value': '463.37'}]},
           'type': 'Section'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Equipment Rental', 'id': '29'},
            {'value': '112.00'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Insurance', 'id': '11'}, {'value': '241.23'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Job Expenses', 'id': '58'},
             {'value': '155.07'}]},
           'Rows': {'Row': [{'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Job Materials',
                 'id': '63'},
                {'value': ''}]},
              'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Decks and Patios',
                   'id': '64'},
                  {'value': '234.04'}],
                 'type': 'Data'},
                {'ColData': [{'value': 'Plants and Soil', 'id': '66'},
                  {'value': '353.12'}],
                 'type': 'Data'},
                {'ColData': [{'value': 'Sprinklers and Drip Systems', 'id': '67'},
                  {'value': '215.66'}],
                 'type': 'Data'}]},
              'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Job Materials'},
                {'value': '802.82'}]},
              'type': 'Section'}]},
           'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Job Expenses'},
             {'value': '957.89'}]},
           'type': 'Section'},
          {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Legal & Professional Fees',
              'id': '12'},
             {'value': '75.00'}]},
           'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Accounting', 'id': '69'},
               {'value': '640.00'}],
              'type': 'Data'},
             {'ColData': [{'value': 'Bookkeeper', 'id': '70'}, {'value': '55.00'}],
              'type': 'Data'},
             {'ColData': [{'value': 'Lawyer', 'id': '71'}, {'value': '400.00'}],
              'type': 'Data'}]},
           'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Legal & Professional Fees'},
             {'value': '1170.00'}]},
           'type': 'Section'},
          {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Maintenance and Repair', 'id': '72'},
             {'value': '185.00'}]},
           'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Equipment Repairs',
                'id': '75'},
               {'value': '755.00'}],
              'type': 'Data'}]},
           'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Maintenance and Repair'},
             {'value': '940.00'}]},
           'type': 'Section'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Meals and Entertainment', 'id': '13'},
            {'value': '28.49'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Office Expenses', 'id': '15'},
            {'value': '18.08'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'ColData': [{'value': 'Rent or Lease', 'id': '17'},
            {'value': '900.00'}],
           'type': 'Data'},
          {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Utilities', 'id': '24'},
             {'value': ''}]},
           'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Gas and Electric', 'id': '76'},
               {'value': '200.53'}],
              'type': 'Data'},
             {'ColData': [{'value': 'Telephone', 'id': '77'}, {'value': '130.86'}],
              'type': 'Data'}]},
           'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Utilities'},
             {'value': '331.39'}]},
           'type': 'Section'}]},
        'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Expenses'},
          {'value': '5237.31'}]},
        'type': 'Section',
        'group': 'Expenses'},
       {'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Net Operating Income'},
          {'value': '4558.46'}]},
        'type': 'Section',
        'group': 'NetOperatingIncome'},
       {'Header': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Other Expenses'}, {'value': ''}]},
        'Rows': {'Row': [{'ColData': [{'value': 'Miscellaneous', 'id': '14'},
            {'value': '2916.00'}],
           'type': 'Data'}]},
        'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Total Other Expenses'},
          {'value': '2916.00'}]},
        'type': 'Section',
        'group': 'OtherExpenses'},
       {'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Net Other Income'},
          {'value': '-2916.00'}]},
        'type': 'Section',
        'group': 'NetOtherIncome'},
       {'Summary': {'ColData': [{'value': 'Net Income'}, {'value': '1642.46'}]},
        'type': 'Section',
        'group': 'NetIncome'}]}}
```

I fetched this Data from Quickbook 'profit and loss' API. The 'Rows' contains a key 'Row' that further contains all the data for DataFrame's row.
Each branch contains a Header which further contains a value that represents the title of a new column.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flatten_json. It works well with nested json. However, your json is quite nested and it's not really suited to a dataframe. set your json = data and run the code below. The .T transposes the dataframe. Maybe you can make sense of the data this way. Otherwise you're going to have process the json object first, then create the dataframe.

```
from flatten_json import flatten
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in data['Rows']['Row'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
df.fillna('')  ###or ??? df.fillna('').T

  Header.ColData.0.value Header.ColData.1.value Rows.Row.0.ColData.0.value Rows.Row.0.ColData.0.id  ... Rows.Row.10.Rows.Row.1.type Rows.Row.10.Summary.ColData.0.value Rows.Row.10.Summary.ColData.1.value Rows.Row.10.type
0                 Income                                     Design income                      82  ...                         NaN                                 NaN                                 NaN              NaN
1     Cost of Goods Sold                                Cost of Goods Sold                      80  ...                         NaN                                 NaN                                 NaN              NaN
2                    NaN                    NaN                        NaN                     NaN  ...                         NaN                                 NaN                                 NaN              NaN
3               Expenses                                       Advertising                       7  ...                        Data                     Total Utilities                              331.39          Section
4                    NaN                    NaN                        NaN                     NaN  ...                         NaN                                 NaN                                 NaN              NaN
5         Other Expenses                                     Miscellaneous                      14  ...                         NaN                                 NaN                                 NaN              NaN
6                    NaN                    NaN                        NaN                     NaN  ...                         NaN                                 NaN                                 NaN              NaN
7                    NaN                    NaN                        NaN                     NaN  ...                         NaN                                 NaN                                 NaN              NaN

[8 rows x 152 columns]
```

and transposed

```
                                                0                   1 2             

    3 4                5 6  7
Header.ColData.0.value                         Income  Cost of Goods Sold            Expenses     Other Expenses
Header.ColData.1.value
Rows.Row.0.ColData.0.value              Design income  Cost of Goods Sold         Advertising      Miscellaneous
Rows.Row.0.ColData.0.id                            82                  80                   7                 14
Rows.Row.0.ColData.1.value                     2250.0               405.0               74.86             2916.0
...                                               ...                 ... ..              ... ..             ... .. ..
Rows.Row.10.Rows.Row.1.ColData.1.value                                                 130.86
Rows.Row.10.Rows.Row.1.type                                                              Data
Rows.Row.10.Summary.ColData.0.value                                           Total Utilities
Rows.Row.10.Summary.ColData.1.value                                                    331.39
Rows.Row.10.type                                                                      Section

[152 rows x 8 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question, So this JSON is highly nested and it can't be flattened into a meaningful data-frame using flatten_json or json_normalize, so I have written a script that is specially created for the Quickbook report APIs.
This will take this nested JSON as an argument and create a data frame out of this. Any highly nested Quickbook report API will work with this.

```
def master(data):
    
    """
    Creates Dataframe using Json received from API
    
    Args:
    data(dictionary)  :  Json response from API
    
    Return:
    Dataframe of data inserted
    
    Example:
    Dataframe = master(data_dict_or_Json)
    
    """
    
    ############### Initial values ###############
    level = 0

    headingdict = {}

    maxlvl, crlist, valuelist, colHeaders, headingdict['Headers'] = [],[],[],[],[]

    current = data['Header']['ReportName']

    for i in data["Columns"]["Column"]:
        colHeaders.append(i["ColTitle"])
    try:
        raw_data = data['Rows']['Row']
    except:
        print('No data Found in {} API'.format(current))
        return
    ############### Initial values ###############

    def header_store(l, r=data['Header']['ReportName']):
        
        "Creates a list of headers for each final value found in Json"
        
        for i in l:
            r += '$' + i
        headingdict['Headers'].append(r)

    def value_extract(Json, valuelist, current, crlist, maxlvl, level):
        
        "Extracts all final values found in nested Json and passes its headers to header_store function"
        
        for i in range(len(Json)):
            if 'Header' in Json[i]:
                current = Json[i]['Header']['ColData'][0]['value']
                new = Json[i]['Rows']['Row']
                crlist.append(current)

                value_extract(new, valuelist, current, crlist, maxlvl, level+1)
                current = Json[i]['Header']['ColData'][0]['value']

            if 'ColData' in Json[i]:
                header_store(crlist)
                valuelist.append(Json[i]['ColData'])
                maxlvl.append(level)

            if i == len(Json)-1:
                try:
                    crlist.pop()
                except:
                    pass

        return valuelist,level-1

    value_extract(raw_data, valuelist, current, crlist,maxlvl,level)


    def get_values_df(valuelist,colHeaders,df={}):
        
        "Creates a data frame from all the values found using value_extract function"
        
        for i in range(len(valuelist)):
            for j in range(len(valuelist[i])):
                if colHeaders[j] not in df:
                    df[colHeaders[j]]=[]
                df[colHeaders[j]].append(valuelist[i][j]['value'])
        responseDf = pd.DataFrame(df)
        return responseDf

    def seperator(indict,lvl,outdict = []):
        
        "Creates a list of lists by splitting each list using $, and adding spaces for hierarchical representation"
        
        for i in indict:
            i = i.split('$')
            if len(i) <= lvl:
                for j in range((lvl)-len(i)):
                    i.append(' ')
                outdict.append(i)
        return outdict

    def heading_lvls(maxlvl,columns=['Form',]):
        
        "Creates Headers column"
        
        for i in range(maxlvl):
            head = 'Header'+'-'+'{}'.format(i+1)
            columns.append(head)
        return columns

    newdf = pd.DataFrame(seperator(headingdict['Headers'],max(maxlvl)+1),columns = heading_lvls(max(maxlvl)))

    result = pd.concat([newdf, get_values_df(valuelist,colHeaders)], axis=1)
    
    return result
```